# fatal error C1047 in release build only

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, fftw

My project uses Visual Studio 2012, and I am using the libfftw-3.3.lib as coming from their page. 
When I build my project in debug, it links and compiles just fine, and I get a working application.
When I set it to release mode, the linker gives me following error:

```
2>LINK : fatal error C1047: The object or library file '../IncludeLibs/libfftw-3.3-x86.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed
```

When I set my project to output a .lib, even in release mode, it works, but not as .dll or .exe

Any idea whats happening, or what I can do to resolve this?

Edit:
my linker settings, debug:

```
/OUT:"G:\GlukoseScanner\GlucoseScanner\Debug\MachineLearning.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"G:\GlukoseScanner\GlucoseScanner\Debug\MachineLearning.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "../debug/GlucoseDLL.lib" "shlwapi.lib" "../PicoScope/ps5000a.lib" "../C/cbw32.lib" "../DSO2250_SDK/Lib/SDK2250DLL.lib" "../IncludeLibs/libfftw-3.3-x86.lib" "../IncludeLibs/libfftwf-3.3-x86.lib" "mlpack.lib" "winmm.lib" "opengl32.lib" "glu32.lib" "..\..\armadillo-4.400.1\build\Release\armadillo.lib" "..\..\armadillo-4.400.1\examples\lib_win32\libblas.lib" "..\..\armadillo-4.400.1\examples\lib_win32\liblapack.lib" "..\libxml2\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\lib\libxml2.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"G:\GlukoseScanner\GlucoseScanner\Debug\MachineLearning.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\MachineLearning.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

The Linkersettings for release:

```
/OUT:"G:\GlukoseScanner\GlucoseScanner\Release\MachineLearning.exe" /MANIFEST /LTCG /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"G:\GlukoseScanner\GlucoseScanner\Release\MachineLearning.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "../release/GlucoseDLL.lib" "shlwapi.lib" "../PicoScope/ps5000a.lib" "../C/cbw32.lib" "../DSO2250_SDK/Lib/SDK2250DLL.lib" "../IncludeLibs/libfftw-3.3-x86.lib" "../IncludeLibs/libfftwf-3.3-x86.lib" "mlpack.lib" "winmm.lib" "opengl32.lib" "glu32.lib" "..\..\armadillo-4.400.1\build\Release\armadillo.lib" "..\..\armadillo-4.400.1\examples\lib_win32\libblas.lib" "..\..\armadillo-4.400.1\examples\lib_win32\liblapack.lib" "..\libxml2\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\lib\libxml2.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"G:\GlukoseScanner\GlucoseScanner\Release\MachineLearning.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\MachineLearning.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right click your project under release configuration
Configuration Properties -> General -> Whole Program Optimization -> "No Whole Program Optimization"

Your linked library may be don't enable LTCG optimization, and VS2012 can't optimize your program with /LTCG.

Comment: and same on the dependencies lib !

Answer (score -3):

> **Any idea whats happening?**

Yes:

> The object or library file '../IncludeLibs/libfftw-3.3-x86.lib' was created with an older compiler than other objects

> **What I can do to resolve this?**

You can:

> rebuild old objects and libraries

Looks like the debug build is linking to different versions of the libraries than the release build. The easiest thing to do would be to download the source code for the library that you're using and build it with the same build system that you're using to build your project.

It rarely works out well to download binary files and try to link them in. You'll run into all sorts of problems if they weren't compiled with the same settings and on a compatible compiler/linker as the one you're trying to use.

Comment: Okay, but how can I rebuilt that? I am not too familiar with MinGW, and how to use that properly, especially making sure it uses the proper toolset I suppose? How do I get the Linux / MinGW source code to create working libraries for VS2012?

Comment: You don't want to rebuild it with MinGW, that defeats the whole point. You want to rebuild it with VS 2012 (or whatever build system you're using for *your* project). That ensures it is compatible.